# Java File Uploader

Tags: java, web

I have a very simple custom java web server (no servlets etc).   I need to support file uploads via browser. Anyone has a pointer?

Comment: are you considering writing servlets for this purpose (or) without writing anycode you want to upload file functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/, fairly easy to implement if you dont mind 3rd party dependencies...

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to implement this RFC http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt

I suggest you take a look at some open source implementation; I find that Jetty's is pretty straight forward, you can take a look at their code here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/

I think you can even reuse some of their code at a binary level if you are ok with this or take it as an implementation hint if you prefer the exercise of writing it from scratch.